# Printing out the n-th byte and the last byte of a file

Tags: ruby

I want to print out both the 7th (or whatever) byte and the last byte of a particular file. I want to do this via the command line using the `ruby` command. (I’m on Mac OS X, but it shouldn’t matter.)

How do I do this?

Comment: Why base64 encode it?  It would be much cleaner to print values in hex.

Comment: Ah, you’re right. That would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints the integer value of each byte, which is a bit more understandable than your request to print in base 64:

```
arr = []

f = File.new("/tmp/test.txt")
 # "This is a test sentence.\n"

f.seek(7)
 # => 0 

arr << f.readbyte
 # => [32]    (The space between 'is' and 'a'.)

f.seek(-1, IO::SEEK_END)
 # => 0 

arr << f.readbyte
 # => [32, 10]    (The newline at the end of the file.)
```

Comment: Important thing to note here is that `f.seek(7)` will actually move to the 8t byte. The bytes are zero indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code of the base64 encoding:

```
require 'Base64'
file = File.open("temp.txt", "r")
byte_array = []
file.seek(6) # go to 7th byte
byte_array << file.getbyte
file.seek(file.size - 1)
byte_array << file.getbyte
Base64.encode64(byte_array.pack('c*'))
```

**EDIT** If you do not want explicitly the base64 encoding then you can also print the byte values like that:

```
puts byte_array * " "
```